# How to generate an on-page preview of a generated PDF using FPDF

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, dynamically-generated, fpdi

I'm able to generate a PDF with PHP using FPDF, but I'm trying to create an on-screen preview of the generated PDF rather than jumping straight to the online PDF viewer.

```
<?php

 use setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
 use setasign\Fpdi\PdfReader;

 require_once('fpdf/fpdf.php');
 require_once('fpdi2/src/autoload.php');

 $pdf = new Fpdi();

 $pageCount = $pdf->setSourceFile('pdf1.pdf');

 for ($pageNo = 1; $pageNo <= $pageCount; $pageNo++)
 {
    $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage($pageNo);

    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->useTemplate($tplIdx, 0, 30);

    $src = $target_file;
    $pdf->Image($src,170,0, 30, 30);

 }

 $pdf->Output();

?>
```

The below code is what I've got at the moment, but i'm stuck on trying to generate it on the same page.

```
$pdf->Output();
```

The above segment seems to generate the PDF automatically onto a new page (opens online PDF viewer). I've searched through documentation and forums but can't seem to find anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FPDF creates a PDF file. A PDF file needs a viewer or reader application, which renders the content of the PDF document. You cannot just output it e.g. between some HTML fragments on a website.

So your question is not related to FPDF or FPDI at all but you're asking for a PDF viewer/render which you can use on your website.

The most popular solution for such task would be [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/).
For other possible canditates you may try "html5 pdf viewer" on google.

Comment: Ah I see. But the same logic still applies. How would I output the generated pdf to be used via that pdf viewer?

Comment: As any other PDF document. It doesn't make any difference if the PDF is generated dynamically or if it is a static one.